# requestHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: unity-game-engine, go, webserver, token, agora

`
I'm trying to regenerate token from server using golang When I host this url in localhost i get rtc and rtm token both in chrome site http://localhost:8080/rte/agora/publisher/uid/1234/

Later I tried to connect with unity this is my webrequest in unity`

```
public static class HelperClass
{
    public static IEnumerator FetchToken(string url, string channel, int userId, Action<string> callback = null) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Hitting Web Request");
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(string.Format("{0}/rtc/{1}/publisher/uid/{2}/", url, channel, userId));
           
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError) 
        {
            Debug.Log("request"+request.error);
            callback(null);
            yield break;
        }

       TokenObject tokenInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenObject>(request.downloadHandler.text);

        callback(tokenInfo.rtcToken);
    }
}
```

`this is my url i tried to get`

```
internal static string _tokenBase = "http://localhost:8080/rte/agora/publisher/uid/";
```

`and I run this using

`

```
StartCoroutine(HelperClass.FetchToken(_tokenBase, _channelName, 0, this.RenewOrJoinToken));
```

`I tried to get auto generate token but I'm getting below issue

`

```
InvalidOperationException: UnityWebRequest has already been sent; cannot begin sending the request again
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.SendWebRequest () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UnityWebRequest/Public/UnityWebRequest.bindings.cs:266)
Agora.Util.HelperClass+<FetchToken>d__0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Agora-RTC-Plugin/API-Example/Tools/RequestToken.cs:27)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Corout
```

Comment: So you have a url. You then send to function which adds on the end that which is already there and are being told it doesnt exist. That makes sense. If you debug your url you make you will see. You also seem to have changed the path in the function. So. There seem to be 2 things wrong